# What is the difference between kafka.consumer.simple.SimpleConsumer.offsets and kafka.consumer.simple.SimpleConsumer.fetch_offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

The API doc is here:http://kafka-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apidoc/kafka.consumer.html

What is the difference between kafka.consumer.simple.SimpleConsumer.offsets and kafka.consumer.simple.SimpleConsumer.fetch_offsets (https://github.com/mumrah/kafka-python/blob/adbd4ac052e4a5b40cfc2a3589b7adbcb656afe5/kafka/consumer/simple.py)?

**How to get the offset of all the messages for certain partition of one topic? How to get the offset of un-consumed messages? How to get the offset of consumed messages?** It seems that offsets and fetch_offsets both are the offset of consumed messages.

Comment: this sounds primarily opinion based to me , look for simpleConsumer API in order to consumer messages from specific partitions, go through the [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/IndeX) doc and their main site .. no offense but you should be more specific with your questions

Comment: I already read their doc. But still confused. I will read further.